# Assign value of currently selected cell in SAP to variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I want to assign the value of a cell selected in SAP to a variable using Visual Basic for Applications so that I can use this value later in the script.

I select the cell with the following:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 6, "DEBIT"
```

How do I assign the value of this SAP cell to a variable or copy the value to a cell in my Excel workbook?

I'm trying to pull the value from SAP TCode FAGLB03 'Balance Display: G/L Accounts For the Ledger 0L'.

[image: Screenshot of TCode trying to pull value from]

I would prefer to not use sendkeys if copying the value as I've found it can be unreliable.

I looked through various forums and attempted the following lines:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").copy
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").getItemText(6, "DEBIT") = amt
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").getItemText(6, 1) = amt
```

Full Code Below:

```vb
Sub SAPAuto()

Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, tbl As ListObject, numrows As Integer, numcolmns As Integer, FiscalYear As Integer, _
    FiscalMonth As Integer, GLAccounts As Range, acct As Integer, co As String, CoCode As Range, amt As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
FiscalYear = wb.Worksheets("Driver").Range("B15").Value
FiscalMonth = wb.Worksheets("Driver").Range("B16").Value
Set GLAccounts = wb.Worksheets("Reference Tables").[GL_Accounts]
Set CoCode = wb.Worksheets("Reference Tables").[Company_Code]


If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
End If
    
For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    co = sh.Range("A1")
    For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
        sh.Activate
        numrows = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        numcolms = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
        session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nFAGLB03"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendvkey 0
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRACCT-LOW").Text = Right(tbl.Name, 5)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRBUKRS-LOW").Text = co
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRYEAR").Text = FiscalYear    'This is varaible
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendvkey 8
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell FiscalMonth, "DEBIT"
        'Need to add a line in here where I can get currentcell value and assign it to variable amt
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(numrows, 4).Value = amt
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell FiscalMonth, "CREDIT" = amt
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(numrows, 5).Value = amt
        'Need to add a line in here where I can get currentcell value and assign it to variable amt
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell FiscalMonth, "BALANCE" = amt
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(numrows, 6).Value = amt
        'Need to add a line in here where I can get currentcell value and assign it to variable amt
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell FiscalMonth, "CUMULATIVE BALANCE" = amt
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(numrows, 7).Value = amt
        'Need to add a line in here where I can get currentcell value and assign it to variable amt
    Next tbl
Next sh

MsgBox "Success"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a GRID, the syntax you are looking for should look like this:

```
amt = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlFDBL_BALANCE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue (6, "DEBIT")
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: Not the hero I deserved, but the hero I needed. Thank you very much ScriptMan this worked

Comment: List of all methods and properties -> [GuiGridView Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiGridView&product=sap_gui_for_windows)